# Show data from a one-to-many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables with a one-to-many relationship.

Table 1:

```
_________________
| id | question  | 
|____|___________|
|  1 | question1 |
|  2 | question2 |
|____|___________|
```

Table 2:

```
______________________________
| id | answer  | question_id |
|____|_________|_____________|
|  1 | answer1 |      1      |
|  2 | answer2 |      1      |
|____|_________|_____________|
```

While `question_id` is the foreign key.

I'm trying to show the data like that:

```
      question1
answer1     answer2
```

So question then the answers for this particular question.

Here is the code I have:

```
$query = "SELECT questions.*, answers.* FROM questions INNER JOIN answers ON questions.id = answers.question_id";

$run = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
    echo $data['question'] . '<br>';
    echo $data['answer'] . '<br>';
}
```

This returns:

```
question1
answer1
question1
answer2
```

So how to show the question only once with the related answers to this particular question?

Comment: There are many ways to do it. One of them is simply nest two queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT` function might come in handy here:

```php
$query = <<<QUERY
SELECT q.question, GROUP_CONCAT(a.answer ORDER BY q.id) answers
FROM questions q
         INNER JOIN answers a ON q.id = a.question_id
GROUP BY q.question
QUERY;

$run = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($data['question'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5), "<br>\n";
    $answers = explode(',', $data['answers']);

    echo '<pre>';
    for ($i=0, $iMax = count($answers); $i < $iMax; $i++) {
        if ($i > 0) echo "<br>\n";
        echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', htmlspecialchars($answers[$i], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5);
    }
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: It's returning 1 question and all the answers. I want to return each question once with its related answes

Comment: I copied/pasted the whole code and it returned the 1st question and all answers for all questions. Instead of each question with its answers

Comment: @user_m You're right, I messed up.  I added a `GROUP BY` clause.  It should work now.